# Access VBA Navigate to a record based on a combobox

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

Imagine a table(tblEmployee) set up  as follows:

1. EmpID(PrimaryKey)
2. EmpName(ShortText)
3. EmpNo(ShortText)
4. EmpPhoto(Attachment)

On a form I want to be able to select Employee's Name from a Combobox(EmpName) so that the other controls update and show me the Number and Photo of the selected employee.

I Have made a form(frmEmployee) and selected the the Record Source as:

```
  SELECT tblEmployee.* FROM tblEmployee;
```

and added all the fields to the form through "Add existing fields" tab. I then changed the textbox(EmpName) to a combobox with two columns, first of which has a width of zero, and changed the Row Source to :

```
SELECT tblEmployee.ID, tblEmployee.EmpName
FROM tblEmployee;
```

So the user can see and choose any employee's name without having to deal with primary keys(EmpID).
Also The afterUpdate event of the combobox(EmpName) is like this:

```
    Private Sub EmpName_AfterUpdate()
' Find the record that matches the control.
    Dim rs As Object

    Set rs = Me.Recordset.Clone
    rs.FindFirst "[ID] = " & Str(Nz(Me![EmpName], 0))
    If Not rs.EOF Then Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
End Sub
```

This gets me the functionality I want but Also **Whenever I choose another Employee Name from the combobox the current Employee's Name is Updated to the ID(EmpID) of the newly selected Employee.**

How to fix this? Also is there any other faster better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an unbound combo box.

To make your current combo box unbound, just remove the `Control Source` property.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you built the form by adding existing fields and then changed the `EmpName` to a ComboBox, the ComboBox *is still bound to the employee's name in the database*!!

What I mean by that is that if you have John Smith's record displayed and you select "Peter Griffin" in the combo box, you just changed John's name to "Peter Griffin".  The functionality you're after is built nicely into *Access* already.  Here's the "standard" way of doing it...

1) Create a form (this will be a subform in a second).  Call it `frmEmployeeDetail`.  Specify the `Record Source` as `tblEmployee` and add all the employee fields to it just like you did before.

2) Now create an unbound form (a form that has *nothing* for the `Record Source`).  Add your ComboBox to it.  Set the `Row Source` to show names just like you did before, but **leave the `Control Source` blank**!  You don't want this ComboBox changing any underlying data.  You just want it to sit there and look pretty for now.  Make sure you set `Bound Column` to 1.  That way the "value" of the ComboBox is the `EmpID` of whatever name you select.  Name the ComboBox `cmbEmpID`.

3) On the unbound form you just created, add a subform (This will be the form you created in step 1).  For `Source Object` put `frmEmployeeDetail`.  For `Link Master Fields` put `cmbEmpID`.  For `Link Child Fields` put `EmpID`.

Now whenever you select a name on the ComboBox, it sets the value of `cmbEmpID` to whatever Employee ID you just selected.  Since you linked that to the subform, the subform will show whatever data matches the ComboBox (because that's what subforms do...)

As far as formatting, you can remove the borders, etc. from the subform and easily blend it right into the "Master" form so that it just looks like one nice form.  Best part: All built-in.  No code.

Comment: I like this approach as well, but since i leads to have more objects I will go with Erik's suggestion. Anyway in your experience, which approach is database manageability wise, better in the long run, to write less code or have less objects?

Comment: Either way.  A large table like an employee table, I like your original approach (with Erik's suggestion to unbind the combo box).  With smaller "category" type tables (like "Employee Departments", "Job TItles", etc.--Tables that only have less than 30 or so entries and are fairly static), I like to use my way.  I use a list box instead of a combo box so I can see all the entries and select the one that I want to set a definition for.  I like this approach for those sorts of tables mostly because those "category" type tables are generally used to populate drop-down menus elsewhere

Comment: ...in your GUI.  So being able to see those options in a list box where I can see all the options, adjust the list order, etc on the "Master" form but set the individual behavior attributes of each option on subform side, I find very useful.  You're right though...  On a big not-so-static table where you are looking up data, your approach is really simpler.  And now you understand why it wasn't working, so it's all preference from here.